# Multi input type text to mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to pass 5 values in same time using this code. 
There is an error in strip_tags. Can any one tell me how to solve it,
php code >

```
$option = strip_tags($_POST['option']);   
$survey_name = strip_tags($_POST['survey_name']);     
if(isset($_POST['sendv'])){
if($option) {
foreach($option as $o){
$resource = mysql_query("INSERT  INTO  options
(value,ques_id) 
VALUES
('$o','$survey_name') 
"
)or die(mysql_error());}
```

html code >

```
<form action="" method="post" >
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Option 1</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Option 2</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Option 3</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Option 4</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]">
</div><div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Option 5</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Survey name</label>
<select class="form-control" name="survey_name" >
<option value="1" >1</option>
</select>           
</div>
<button type="submit" name="sendv" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
</form>
```

When I post it, this error appears..
strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: **DO NOT** use `mysql_` it's been deprecated and it's unsafe. Use `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: And what is unclear? `$_POST['option']` is array.

Comment: iknow but this web is local

Comment: print_r 
Array ( [0] => sfsf [1] => ssf [2] => fsf [3] => sfs [4] => fsfs

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: If you flippped this to use prepared statements you could iterate over the array you have with no problems. `strip_tags` is completley and utterly useless for SQL escaping and should **NOT** be used in this context. Ever. It is singularly concerned with making things safe for HTML and HTML only.

Comment: There are so many security problems with this code I hesitate to offer this, but if I were bold enough to provide an answer (nope, wouldn't, because the entire code pretty much is dangerous, but that wasn't your question), the answer to your question is `implode` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). This converts the array into a string. In this example, it will be comma separated:

`$option = strip_tags(implode(",",$_POST['option']));` Also, storing data like this is not good relational database practice, but that is an entirely different subject.

Comment: @Justin implode(): Invalid arguments passed  ?

Comment: My bad. Didn't really look closely enough and missed the foreach loop. Instead, you would not `strip_tags` on the first line. In your `foreach` add a line at the top: `$o = strip_tags($o);` Again, this is pretty dangerous code.

Comment: Are these the real names of your input fields? you have names them name="option[]"